# cannot install pyproject.toml-based projects python 3.9.2

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

[I am tying to install kivy in python 3.9.2, but it shows this problem, Which is I don't know How to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRtly.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the latest cutting-edge version from [master](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master) using `python -m pip install "kivy[base] @ https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip"`, it should work